# How to prevent Apache Camel delegating route parameters to called route url

Tags: routes, apache-camel, route-parameters

I'm trying to get in touch with Apache Camel, but it's behaviour is so far confusing.

For example, I'm using platformHttp and declare a route under which my endpoint should be available.

```
from(platformHttp("/api/test"))
     .to("https:google.com?bridgeEndpoint=true")
     .setBody(simple("${body}"));
```

Calling it will call the sub-route **https://google.com/api/test** instead of **https://google.com**

Why is that and how would I prevent Apache Camel from taking the route and appending it to the called route in my .to() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent the HTTP exchange headers (I.e ones with names prefixed with `CamelHttp`) being propagated from the `platform-http` endpoint to the `http` endpoint, you can remove them like this.

```
from(platformHttp("/api/test"))
     .removeHeaders("CamelHttp*")
     .to("https:google.com?bridgeEndpoint=true")
     .setBody(simple("${body}"));
```

There's an FAQ article for this topic on the Camel website:

https://camel.apache.org/manual/faq/how-to-remove-the-http-protocol-headers-in-the-camel-message.html

Comment: I agree . one addition from me with this you dont need to bridgeEndpoint

Comment: thanks for your help. Do you know if it would also be possible to remove them when using the REST DSL?